Comparing two regression coefficients within a generalized linear model
I've fit a generalized linear model using glm:
mod <- glm(
    formula = "All_Time_PB ~ Men_PV_first + Men_PV_delta",
    data = dec_data,
    family=Gamma()
)

The data that has 2 predictors and 1 outcome variable, all continuous. I'm interested in testing if the coefficient Men_PV_first is significantly greater than the coefficient for Men_PV_delta.
What's the most appropriate statistical test to apply and what would be the best way to implement it in R?

How large is the dataset? You could try bootstrapping the difference of the coefficients. But a simple t-test should also be fine (based on asymptotic normality).

Thanks for your help! I have 642 observations; any particular considerations for performing the t-test? I'm thinking specifically that summary(mod) only provides the standard error of the mean rather than the standard deviation, although I suppose it would be easy to get from one to the other.

The vcov function is useful. The main issue is that the coefficient estimates are not independent. That's why I would prefer the bootstrap.

That makes sense; I think I understand -- so it would essentially be bootstrap sampling to determine the mean of Men_PV_first - Men_PV_delta? Then, we could see what proportion of the bootstrap sampled mean values are greater than 0 to determine if the difference is significant? One thing I'm wondering about is how to do that if we only have one value to sample from for Men_PV_first - Men_PV_delta. Would I use the mean and SEM?

What do you mean by "have one value to sample from"? You have 642 observations to sample from (with replacement).

I think I understand -- so I would create n samples of size x sampling with replacement and then compute the coefficients for all of those samples?

Be careful with this type of comparison. It only makes sense if the two predictors are on the same scale, and only partial sense (at best) if they are correlated. In this case, from the names I suspect that Men_PV_first has a much larger spread of values than Men_PV_delta, so the comparison of their coefficients might not make sense. Remember that, for example, the coefficient for a distance predictor measured in kilometers will be different from that for the same distance predictor measured in millimeters, by a factor of 1 million.

@EdM That makes great sense; the two variables are on the same scale since all predictors were preprocessed using robust scaling. I don't exactly recall the spread of the two variables offhand, so I'm not certain about that. However, I remember that those two variables specifically were not highly correlated. There were two (Men_SP_first and Men_DT_first, if I recall) that were correlated at something like 0.708. We decided to include both of them in the analysis for completeness, although it might have been better to remove one of the two.

I would bootstrap the difference between the coefficients. Here is a simple example with OLS regression.
#simulate some data, since none is provided
set.seed(42)

x1 <- runif(100, 0, 100)
x2 <- 1:100

y <- 100 + 0.1 * x1 + 0.12 * x2 + rnorm(100)

DF <- data.frame(x1, x2, y)

#fit model
fit <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = DF)
summary(fit)

#bootstrap the difference between coefficients
library(boot)
set.seed(42)
nboot <- 9999
myboot <- boot(DF, \(DF, i) {
  #error catching in case fit fails for some bootstrap resamples
  tryCatch({
    DF <- DF[i,] #resampling
    fit <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = DF)
    coef(fit)[["x1"]] - coef(fit)[["x2"]]
    },
    error = \(e) NA #return NA if fit fails
  )
}, R = nboot)

#check if too many fits failed
mean(is.na(myboot$t))

#confidence interval
boot.ci(myboot, type = "bca")
#Level       BCa          
#95%   (-0.0199, -0.0056 )  

See this post for p-values.

Thanks so much for your help! I really appreciate it.
